# Array of images creates animation

Tags: java, animation, imageicon

I am trying to create an animation. Two images are supposed to move - car and human. But human consists of two images, so that it looks like a proper movement. I am trying to put the array of images into my code, but it does not work. Could you, please,  help with it?
Here is my code

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable{
int x=0;

public Image car = new ImageIcon( "car.png").getImage();
public Image[] human;
private Thread thread;

public Main() {
    super("Animation");
    this.setSize(700,500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());//background

    g.drawImage(car,x,150,null);

    human = new Image[2];
    human[0] = new ImageIcon("move.png").getImage();
    human[1] = new ImageIcon("stop.png").getImage();

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        g.drawImage(human[i], x , 200,null);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main f = new Main();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);      
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true)
    {
        x++; 

        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean does not work? Do you get an error? Not the desired result?

Comment: It displays only one image and it does not change, so this is not the desired result